# How do I flatten a NonEmpty of NonEmptys

Tags: haskell

Data.List.NonEmpty

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List-NonEmpty.html

How do I flatten a NonEmpty of NonEmptys -- staying within NonEmpty? IOW I do not want to convert to regular list and do a concat and then convert back to NonEmpty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As `NonEmpty` is a `Monad` you can use [`join`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join):

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

Specialized to `NonEmpty`:

```
join :: NonEmpty (NonEmpty a) -> NonEmpty a
```

Comment: This is the answer that [a quick Hoogle search](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=NonEmpty%20(NonEmpty%20a)%20-%3E%20NonEmpty%20a) for exactly the type asked-for in the question would turn up, as well.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`sconcat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#v:sconcat) from [Data.Semigroup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html).  It combines the elements of a nonempty list using `<>`, which in this case means concatenation.

(It's found there rather than in Data.List.NonEmpty because it's a method of the Semigroup class.)